# Youtube looks funny

Tags: youtube, html

I just installed Ubuntu and my youtube looks like this http://s020.radikal.ru/i714/1601/4c/e5437a0a474f.png
All the other sites (as far as i know) are alright.
Fifefox shows the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Looks like JavaScript and/or CSS failed to load on youtube.com. It should be temporary problem (probably with your ISP network) if all other devices in your house have this issue.

### Troubleshooting Steps

Most of these aren't likely to help if you didn't tamper with your Ubuntu installation.

1. Try changing your DNS to google's DNS servers -> 8.8.8.8. The reasoning being your default ISP DNS can be discarding requests owing to load issues.
2. Check if you router has some blocking policies turned on, like specific URL's being blocked.
3. Check if you are using some proxy server that is configured to drop requests (seems the most likely issue).

Comment: no, my mobile phone loads it properly using the same wifi

Comment: here's whats happening in css http://s011.radikal.ru/i315/1601/94/0a796e649366.png

Comment: Seems like an issue with the DNS on your new Ubuntu installation or with your web browser. This might be helpful - http://superuser.com/questions/719559/why-cant-chrome-load-a-web-page-err-name-not-resolved